# CountClick method for buttons not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a few buttons in my webpage and was trying to restrict the button clicks by having a countClick method to check the number of clicks the users have pressed. In my codes below, when users click on the first button, the second button will automatically be clicked for them. And if they were to choose the second button instead, the third button will be clicked for them automatically too and so on for the rest of the buttons. However in my case, they can only click once as one click accounts for 2 buttons to be clicked. So, when they have clicked once, i cannot allow them to click on the second time.

My problem is that my countClick method is not working. When i run my page, all my buttons can be selected and it does not restrict the user to only 1 button click.

Here is my .cs code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button1.Text = "Booked";
    Button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
    Button2.Text = "Booked";
    Button2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
    countButtonClick();
}
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button2.Text = "Booked";
    Button2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
    Button3.Text = "Booked";
    Button3.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
    countButtonClick();
}
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button3.Text = "Booked";
    Button3.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
    Button4.Text = "Booked";
    Button4.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
    countButtonClick();
}
protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button4.Text = "Booked";
    Button4.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
    countButtonClick();
}
```

Here is my countClick method in .cs:

```
private void countButtonClick()
{
    int counter = 0;
    counter++;
    if (counter >= 1)
    {
        Response.Write("You can only select 2 slots! " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you specify when the user (or even multiple users?) can click and how often? It's not very clear. How long is he restricted to click any button? You should use a database to store it.

Comment: Each time the users can only select the one button at a time to book a timing. As my logic is that when users click on that particular button, the next button will also activate for the user automatically. Here is a website example i want to implement but the difference is that this website helps users to automatically click on 6 buttons but for my case is only 2 buttons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Store `counter` as a session variable.

Because you are declaring it inside your function, it is unique for that specific instance of that call to the function. Therefore it is reset to 0 each time.

```
private void countButtonClick()
{    
    int counter = 0;
    if (!(Session["counter"])){
       counter = (int)Session["counter"];
    }
    counter++;
    Session["counter"] = counter;

    if (counter >= 1)
    {
        Response.Write("You can only select 2 slots! " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}
```

I would then also ensure the session value is lost when a refresh is made by adding the following to your Page Load method:

```
if (!(Page.IsPostBack)){
   Session["counter"] = null;
}
```

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Ha +1 for your efforts :)

Comment: But this will not work since all variables are disposed on each postback at the end of the page's lifecycle.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Very good point. I've edited my post accordingly

Comment: I have an error that occur here:
if (!(Session["counter"])){
       counter = Session["counter"];
    }
Error 1: "!" Operator cannot be applied to operand of type object and 
Error 2: Cannot implicitly convert a type "object" to "int"

Comment: @kelly Session variables are all stored as `object`. You need to cast them to the appropriate type when getting them out of Session. Take a peek at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx).

Comment: @kelly Changes have been made to the code to set the variable as an `int`. Sorry, I'm too used to VB.NET (unfortunately).

Answer (score 4):

I see two problems here:

First, `counter` needs to be a session variable, and second, you should probably call countClick() before modifying anything on the page, and making it return `bool` so you can tell if it succeeded or not.

```
private bool countClick()
{
    if (Session["clicks"] == null)
    {
        Session["clicks"] = 1;
        return true;
    }
    if (++((int)Session["clicks"]) > 1)
    {
         Response.Write("...");
         return false;
    }
    return true;
}


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (countClick())
    {
        Button1.Text = "Booked";
        Button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
        Button2.Text = "Booked";
        Button2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to ask, but what does the "clicks" here in the Session refers to?

Comment: It is just a key in the Session collection.  It could be any string.  I had a typo, forgot to quote it. :)

Answer (score 3):

Your `countButtonClick` method uses `counter` as a locally scoped variable, by declaring it inside the method. This means every time the method is called, the counter will be created and initialized to 0. Additionally, the number of clicks won't be preserved across postbacks. Even if you move the counter declaration outside of `countButtonClick`, every time a button is clicked, the counter variable will be reset to 0, because of how the [page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) works. The way to resolve this is to store the counter in some fashion, such as session or view state.

```
private int counter = 0;
protected void Page_Load()
{
   if(!Page.IsPostback)
   {
      ViewState["MyClickCounter"] = 0;
   }
   else
   {
      counter = (int)ViewState["MyClickCounter"];
   }
}
private void countButtonClick()
{
   counter++;
   ViewState["MyClickCounter"] = counter;
   if (counter >= 1)
   {
      Response.Write("You can only select 2 slots! " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
   }
}
```

You also may want to add a reset method, depending on what your page needs to do.